# Find the average speed for roads

Tags: api, map

I am working on a mobile application and I would like to ask you a question. Is there an API or a method to get/calculate the average speed that a car should have in a road. I am working on a GPS like application and I want to calculate the average time that it will take a user to cover a certain path.

Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing this isn't available for free (maximum allowed speed at each road) and you will have to purchase it from somewhere. Perhaps the Google Maps API, but this is also paid for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will require you to access some database(s) which hold maximum allowed speeds for each road. Looking to purchase such information can turn out to be quite costly, especially if you want to cover wide areas. Combining several different data sources can also result in some extra required effort.

Probably it's best to use an existing service, like Google Maps. A [quick look at their API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService) indicates they can provide you with some of the information you need.